# How to make a "longtable" take up less space?

Tags: longtable

I have a big problem with tables using LaTeX. I need your help to make the following table shorter and more compact. I have got unsatisfactory results so far. The first two columns and the last column could be combined into a single column. So, keep 3 columns. The spaces between sentences can be reduced and if possible make it on just 2 pages. Please, help.

[image]

The code:

```
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Thesis.tex -- MAIN FILE (the one that you compile with LaTeX)
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

% Set up the document

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, arial, oneside]{Thesis}   % Use the "Thesis" document class, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn

\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
%\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
%\renewcommand\familydefault{phv}



%\graphicspath{{figs/}}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics to be in PDF format)

% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
%\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  % Colours hyperlinks in blue, but this can be distracting if there are many links.

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{enumerate}


%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[hmargin={30mm,25mm},vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}

%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
%   \setlist[itemize]{  nosep,     % <-- new list setup
%       leftmargin = *,
%       before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
%       after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
%   }
%}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e, tabularx}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, makecell, threeparttablex}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{%
    \small                              % for better fit text into cells
    \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth} % that caption width is equal table width
    \setlist[itemize]{  nosep,          % <-- new list setup
        leftmargin = *,
        before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    }
}% end of AtBeginEnvironment

\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
        wide,%leftmargin = *,
        before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    }
}% end of AtBeginEnvironment

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\setlength\parskip{0.2\baselineskip}\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=red}
% You can conditionalize code for latexml or normal latex using this.
\newif\iflatexml\latexmlfalse
\providecommand{\tightlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}%

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.PDF,.png,.PNG,.jpg,.JPG,.jpeg,.JPEG}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}


% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{siunitx} % For units
\newcommand\mmfeed[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf,small},textfont={small}}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont={bf,small}, textfont={small}, subrefformat=parens} %<-----designing subcaption
\newcommand{\myfigref}[2]{~\ref{#1}.\subref{#2}}% <---- a new macro for referring to a subfigure
%    

%\newpage
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{bibliografia}

% Change the text font
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
%



\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cleveref}


% I added many usepackages
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


    \begin{longtable}{
            R{\dimexpr0.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
            R{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
            R{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
            R{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
            R{\dimexpr0.15\linewidth-4\tabcolsep}
        }

        \caption{The state-of-the-art in taxonomy, detection, extraction and pattern recognition in urban applications}
        \label{T2.5}    \\
        \toprule
        %& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Consequences of the expansion of cities}
        %\\
        %\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
        \textbf{Application} & \textbf{Taxonomy/quantification algorithms} & \textbf{Merits} & \textbf{Limitations} & \textbf{Example} 
        \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \caption{The state-of-the-art in \dots\hfill (cont. from previous page)}
        %\\
        %\toprule
        %& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Consequences of the expansion of cities}
        %\\
        %\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
        %& Temperature  & Air quality & Water quality
        \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continued on the next page}}
        \endfoot
        \endlastfoot
        %%%%

        Seismic building structural types (SBSTs)
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Support vector machine (SVM) and random forest (RF)
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Classify the combination of different remote sensing data
            \item   Derive sets of valuable features to characterise the urban environment
            \item   Model an effective earthquake loss and spatial distribution
            \item   ABTSVM classifier outperforms other multi-class SVM classifiers
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Hierarchical supervised classification scheme has uncertainties in separating SBSTs
            \item   Performance depends on the ranked features
            \item   Accuracy is subject to the addition of further features and subset based categories
        \end{itemize} 
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   \cite{geiss2015}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Urban change detection: landuse transitions
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Scene classification with a bag-of-visual-words (BOVW)
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Obtain semantic scene classes
            \item   Effectively analyse landuse changes
            \item   Satisfactory accuracy
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Time-consuming
            \item   Very difficult to achieve the direct selection of the “from-to” samples from the dataset
            \item   Classification performance in certain cases is negatively affected by the redundancy of information
        \end{itemize} 
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   \cite{wu2016}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Urban landcover and landuse classification
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Binary tree SVM based on Jeffries–Matusita (JM) distance
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Improve classification accuracy
            \item   Classify hyperspectral images adequately
            \item   Ease of interpretation of urban classes
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Confusion between road and bare soil classes
            \item   Instability and complexity in the structure and parameters of the binary tree SVM
        \end{itemize} 
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   \cite{du2012}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Monitoring changes in impervious surfaces
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   MRGU
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Integrate multiple endmember spectral mixture analysis (MESMA), analysis of regression residuals, spatial statistics (Getis Ord) with Moran’s I, and urban growth theories in an effective manner
            \item   Quantify and identify the magnitude of impervious surface changes and their spatial distribution
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Not universally applicable due to specific behaviour of maximum noise fraction (MNF)
            \item  Difficult to use for quantifying changes in urban centres
            \item  Performance (regression residuals) is subject to the structure of urban regions
        \end{itemize} 
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{shahtahmassebi2016}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Change detection
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Unsupervised Neural network and feature transformation
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Deep architecture (SDAE) for better representation of the relationships between feature- and pixel-pair
            \item  Mapping based FCA and function learning to highlight change in a robust manner
            \item  Denoising autoencoder
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Uncertainty in the feature-pair
            \item  High computational cost
            \item  Complexity structures of stacked denoising autoencoders (SDAE)
            \item  Many constraints are required to extract useful features
        \end{itemize} 
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{zhang2016}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Water quality, and sustainable water resources management
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Integrated data fusion and mining (IDFM) and artificial neural network (ANN)
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  A near real-time monitoring and the early warning system
            \item  Efficiency
            \item  Forecasting reliability
            \item  Potential for local adoption
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Prediction accuracy may be effected by uncertainties in the fused data
            \item  A large number of variables is required to overcome the uncertainty
            \item  Not applicable for regional meteorology parameters
        \end{itemize} 
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{imen2015}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Air temperature estimation
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   SVM
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Fully automated method
            \item  SVM regression is robust
            \item  Regression errors can be modelled at the pixel level, improving accuracy estimation
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Requires expert users to apply SVM
            \item  Does not work well under non cloud-free conditions and require in situ measurements
            \item  Regression error distribution is insufficient
        \end{itemize} 
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{moser2015}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Fine-scale population estimation for urban management, emergency response and epidemiological
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item RF
            \item Linear regression modelling
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Able to classify building types and extract their footprints in the heterogeneous urban areas
            \item  Improved classification accuracy
            \item  Ease of adoption
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Subject to the accuracy of the selected morphology filter
            \item  Use of large numbers of metrics and variables for building type classification
            \item  Building background metrics do not show its advantage in the block classification
            \item  Classification uncertainty for non-residential buildings
        \end{itemize} 
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{xie2015}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Renewable energy and urban feature extraction
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item Shadow detection and building geometry identification
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Easy to apply
            \item  Sufficient to generate 3D model of urban buildings
            \item  Reliable analysis of the solar energy potential
            \item  Identify the availability of 3D surfaces
            \item  Flexibility and feasibility
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Not fully automated
            \item  Not suitable for dense urban areas
            \item  Sensitive to the quality of satellite images
        \end{itemize} 
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{kadhim2015a}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Impervious surfaces estimation
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item SVM 
            \item RF
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Increased classification accuracy
            \item  Does not depend on combinations of features
            \item  Data can be fused to optimise parameters efficiently
            \item  Ease of application
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Needs many texture matrices
            \item  Inability to handle the confusion in shaded areas and bare soil
            \item  Over-fitting
        \end{itemize} 
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{zhang2015}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do we get the `Thesis` class? There are myriads of  homonymous classes.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is not really a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Can you give us a minimal piece of compliable code that demonstrates your problem? Note also that `Thesis.cls` is an unknown class file....

Comment: why the rather odd looking `R{\dimexpr0.15\linewidth-4\tabcolsep}` (that relies on 2`\tabcolsep` being at least `.05\linewidth`)  rather than `R{\dimexpr0.1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing *which* of the nearly limitless number of document classes called `Thesis` you employ, the following solution uses the `report` document class instead, along with the assumption of an A4 paper size and 2.5 cm margins. Obviously, feel free to adjust These settings as needed.

The main suggestion I'd like to make is make columns 1, 2, and 5 narrower and, conversely, make columns 3 and 4 wider. That way, it is indeed possible to make the `longtable` fit on two full pages.

I wouldn't use `itemize` environments in the second column unless there is really more than one item in the list.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,arial,oneside]{report}%{Thesis} % which "Thesis"?!

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % choose page parameters suitably


%\usepackage{charter}  % no need to load this package, right?
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} % use Helvetica as main text font

\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{verbatim,vector}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}


\usepackage{graphicx,romannum}

\usepackage{ragged2e, tabularx}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, makecell, threeparttablex}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{%
    \small        
    \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth}
    \setlist[itemize]{  nosep,          % <-- new list setup
        leftmargin = *,
        before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    }
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
        wide,%leftmargin = *,
        before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    }
}

\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[space]{grffile}
%%%%\usepackage{latexsym} % deprecated and superseded by "amssymb"
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}

% You can conditionalize code for latexml or normal latex using this.
\newif\iflatexml\latexmlfalse
\providecommand{\tightlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}


% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor quan-ti-fi-ca-tion}
\usepackage{siunitx} % For units
\newcommand\mmfeed[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf,small},textfont={small},
                      skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont={bf,small}, textfont={small},
                        subrefformat=parens} 
\newcommand{\myfigref}[2]{~\ref{#1}.\subref{#2}}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % load this package (almost) last
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
            %pdfborder={0 0 0},
            linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=red}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}
            R{\dimexpr0.15\linewidth-1\tabcolsep}
            R{\dimexpr0.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
            R{\dimexpr0.30\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
            R{\dimexpr0.30\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
            R{\dimexpr0.10\linewidth-1\tabcolsep} 
            @{}}

        \caption{State-of-the-art in taxonomy, detection, extraction 
             and pattern recognition in urban applications}
        \label{T2.5}    \\
        \toprule
        \textbf{Application} & \textbf{Taxonomy\slash quantification algorithms} & \textbf{Merits} & \textbf{Limitations} & \textbf{Example} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \caption{The state-of-the-art in \dots\hfill (cont.\ from previous page)} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead

        \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize\textit{continued on the next page}}
        \endfoot

        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot

        %%%%

        Seismic building structural types (SBSTs)
        &  Support vector machine (SVM) and random forest (RF)
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Classify the combination of different remote sensing data
            \item   Derive sets of valuable features to characterise the urban environment
            \item   Model an effective earthquake loss and spatial distribution
            \item   ABTSVM classifier outperforms other multi-class SVM classifiers
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Hierarchical supervised classification scheme has uncertainties in separating SBSTs
            \item   Performance depends on the ranked features
            \item   Accuracy is subject to the addition of further features and subset based categories
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   \cite{geiss2015}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Urban change detection: landuse transitions
        & Scene classification with a bag-of-visual-words (BOVW)
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Obtain semantic scene classes
            \item   Effectively analyse landuse changes
            \item   Satisfactory accuracy
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Time-consuming
            \item   Very difficult to achieve the direct selection of the “from-to” samples from the dataset
            \item   Classification performance in certain cases is negatively affected by the redundancy of information
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   \cite{wu2016}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Urban landcover and landuse classification
        & Binary tree SVM based on Jeffries--Matusita (JM) distance
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Improve classification accuracy
            \item   Classify hyperspectral images adequately
            \item   Ease of interpretation of urban classes
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Confusion between road and bare soil classes
            \item   Instability and complexity in the structure and parameters of the binary tree SVM
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   \cite{du2012}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Monitoring changes in impervious surfaces
        & MRGU
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Integrate multiple endmember spectral mixture analysis (MESMA), analysis of regression residuals, spatial statistics (Getis Ord) with Moran’s I, and urban growth theories in an effective manner
            \item   Quantify and identify the magnitude of impervious surface changes and their spatial distribution
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Not universally applicable due to specific behaviour of maximum noise fraction (MNF)
            \item  Difficult to use for quantifying changes in urban centres
            \item  Performance (regression residuals) is subject to the structure of urban regions
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{shahtahmassebi2016}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Change detection
        & Unsupervised Neural network and feature transformation
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Deep architecture (SDAE) for better representation of the relationships between feature- and pixel-pair
            \item  Mapping based FCA and function learning to highlight change in a robust manner
            \item  Denoising autoencoder
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Uncertainty in the feature-pair
            \item  High computational cost
            \item  Complexity structures of stacked denoising autoencoders (SDAE)
            \item  Many constraints are required to extract useful features
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{zhang2016}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Water quality, and sustainable water resources management
        & Integrated data fusion and mining (IDFM) and artificial neural network (ANN)
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  A near real-time monitoring and the early warning system
            \item  Efficiency
            \item  Forecasting reliability
            \item  Potential for local adoption
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Prediction accuracy may be effected by uncertainties in the fused data
            \item  A large number of variables is required to overcome the uncertainty
            \item  Not applicable for regional meteorology parameters
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{imen2015}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Air temperature estimation
        & SVM
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Fully automated method
            \item  SVM regression is robust
            \item  Regression errors can be modelled at the pixel level, improving accuracy estimation
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Requires expert users to apply SVM
            \item  Does not work well under non cloud-free conditions and require in situ measurements
            \item  Regression error distribution is insufficient
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{moser2015}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Fine-scale population estimation for urban management, emergency response and epidemiological
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item RF
            \item Linear regression modelling
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Able to classify building types and extract their footprints in the heterogeneous urban areas
            \item  Improved classification accuracy
            \item  Ease of adoption
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Subject to the accuracy of the selected morphology filter
            \item  Use of large numbers of metrics and variables for building type classification
            \item  Building background metrics do not show its advantage in the block classification
            \item  Classification uncertainty for non-residential buildings
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{xie2015}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Renewable energy and urban feature extraction
        & Shadow detection and building geometry identification
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Easy to apply
            \item  Sufficient to generate 3D model of urban buildings
            \item  Reliable analysis of the solar energy potential
            \item  Identify the availability of 3D surfaces
            \item  Flexibility and feasibility
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Not fully automated
            \item  Not suitable for dense urban areas
            \item  Sensitive to the quality of satellite images
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{kadhim2015a}
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \midrule

        Impervious surfaces estimation
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item SVM
            \item RF
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Increased classification accuracy
            \item  Does not depend on combinations of features
            \item  Data can be fused to optimise parameters efficiently
            \item  Ease of application
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  Needs many texture matrices
            \item  Inability to handle the confusion in shaded areas and bare soil
            \item  Over-fitting
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item  \cite{zhang2015}
        \end{itemize}  \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico-Thank you very much for your help. Your solution works well with my doc. I've managed to reduce the first two columns and I merged the last one with the first columns. Please, I just wonder how to make the 1.5 vertical space between lines shorter. I edited my post and put a pic. Thank you.

Comment: @Iris - Do you know how the file `Thesis.cls` goes about increasing the interline spacing by a factor of 1.5? Knowing the method is crucial for (re)setting the line spacing to "singlespacing" inside the `longtable` environment.

Comment: @Mico-Thank you for your reply. I do not know exactly but I've noticed this command "\setstretch{1.5}". I just wonder if it is possible to minimise/reduce the vertical spaces within this table only? I can send you the .cls file by email. Thank you.

Comment: @Iris - Good news: the presence of the directive `\setstretch{1.5}` most likely means that the `Thesis` document class loads and makes use of the `setspace` package. If you insert the directive `\setstretch{1.0}` immediately after `\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\small`, single-spacing will be in force automatically for all `longtable` environments. If, however, you want single-spacing to apply to just this one `longtable` environment, insert the instructions `\begingroup\setstretch{1.0}` immediately *before* `\begin{longtable}` and `\endgroup` immediately *after* `\end{longtable}`.

Comment: @Mico-You are awesome :) Thank you very much.